# Unbound Value for List.i

Tags: ocaml

I keep getting an unbound value error in this code segment:

```
let count element list =
  let counter = 0 in
    for i = 0 to List.length list do
      if element == List.i list then
        counter = counter + 1 
      else
        counter = counter
    done ;;
```

The code is supposed to take a list and a value from the user and then count how many times the value appears in that list, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Unbound value List.i
```

I am still a beginner to Ocaml any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List.i` does not exist in ***`Ocaml`***.

You are trying to check if the i<sup>th</sup> element of the list is equal to element.

`List.nth` does the trick:

> ```
> List.nth list i
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> List.i list
> ```

The final code :

```
let count element list =
  let counter = ref 0 in
    for i = 0 to (List.length list - 1) do
      if element == List.nth list i then
        counter := !counter + 1 
      else
        counter := !counter
    done ;
 !counter;;
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but after doing that and working out some type errors i got another error,

Comment: I got this error ` for i = 0 to List.length list do
                         ^^^`

Comment: yes, there is still some errors in your code ;) notably you assign a value  to counter which is not mutable in your code.*

Comment: Yeah i figure that out and used 2 other functions instead of using counter but do you have any idea about the for loop error? i don't understand i received a syntax error

Comment: there is more straitghtforward way : one could use the function List.filter to retrieve only the elements equal to the expected value; then apply List.length to the result.

Comment: I'll try the suggested method that you mentioned, but when i try to use the code you gave me it says 'Exception: Failure "nth".' What does that mean?

Comment: exception due to missing nth element : the loops goes one step too far - the code attemps to access an element that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, ocaml's learning curve is steeper than that of c, and there isn't much informational content around, thank you again :)

Comment: One good MOOC : https://www.fun-mooc.fr/courses/parisdiderot/56002S02/session02/about (in english now- I did the 1st session last year ; registration is closed - you'll have to wait for the next session ;) )

Comment: I'll check it when it opens, i tried using the filter and length functions, do you mind telling me why this implementation is incorrect please?

Comment: ` let count ( element, list) =
      let elements = List.filter ( fun x -> ( x = element ) -> true ) in
        let chosen = List.length elements ;; `

Comment: i get the  Syntax error: ')' expected, the highlighted '(' might be unmatched at the brackets before fun.

Comment: Never mind i got it to work :D, this is the code in case anyone wanted it :

Comment: let count ( element, list) = List.length(List.filter ( fun x-> x = element ) list);;